# What are all the @Configuration naming rules for beans?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-ioc

I have some integration tests that are supposed to mock out one of many beans in my system.  To do this, I have a `@Configuration` that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MockContext {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RealBean realBean() {
        return new MockBean();
    }
}
```

I noticed that this method gets used if `RealBean` is a java class **without** `@Component`.  But if `RealBean` **is** a `@Component`, I have to change this context method to look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MockContext {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RealBean getRealBean() {
        return new MockBean();
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why I need to change this method name and where I can find all these rules?  It takes a very long time to troubleshoot these "why isn't my `MockContext` working correctly?" issues.

FWIW, here's how I'm using this context in a test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {RealContext.class, MockContext.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {
```

And my integration test will extend this class.  I am using Spring Boot 1.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: I am afraid there is any place where such rules are written. in general spring strip off "get" from method name and try with camel case to get bean instance .

Comment: @Bhupi well in my second snippet that is not true.

Comment: Do you have a component scan you aren't showing? Also, try to retrieve a bean of type `MockBean` from your context.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no re: component scan.  I'm using Spring Boot FWIW.  Retrieving `MockBean` works fine, I tested in both situations.

Answer (score 2):

You can have various beans registered with same type. But they need to have different names.

If you use `@Bean` annotation [without name attribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-customizing-bean-naming), name of the bean is extracted from method name (in your case realBean/getRealBean).

When you use `@Component` annotation without attribute (which specifies bean name), name of the bean is extracted from method name where [first letter is lowercased](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beanname).

So with your first case, you get a name clash. You can't have two beans named `realBean`.

Your second example is without clash because bean annotated by `@Component` has name `realBean` and second bean registered via `@Bean` has name `getRealBean`.

`@Primary` annotation helps Spring choose which bean to pick if there are two of the same type and you **inject by type**. When you **inject by name** (usage of `@Qualifier` annotation), you can inject also secondary instance.